# Am I understanding Gaussian Distribution correctly?

Tags: probability, normal-distribution

> $X ~ \mathcal{N}(0, \sigma^2)$.
>   Find $Pr(X\geq 0.75\alpha | |X|\geq0.5)$
>   Find $E[X| |X|\geq0.5]$

Is my approach to this problem correct?
Attempt on #1
$$Pr(X\geq 0.75\alpha | |X|\geq0.5) = \frac{Pr(\left\{X\geq0.75\alpha\right\}\cap\left\{|X|\geq0.5\right\})}{Pr(|X| \geq0.5)}$$
$$=\frac{Pr(\left\{X\geq0.75\alpha\right\}\cap\left\{|X|\geq0.5\right\}}{Pr(\left\{X \geq0.5)\right\}\cap\left\{X\leq-0.5\right\})}$$
$$\left\{X\leq-0.5\right\}\;on\;denominator\;is\;removed,\;because\;no\;probability\;for\;negative$$
$$=\frac{Pr(\left\{X\geq0.75\alpha\right\}\cap\left\{|X|\geq0.5\right\})}{Pr(\left\{X \geq0.5\right\})}$$
$$\left\{X\geq0.75\alpha\right\}\cap\left\{|X|\geq0.5\right\} = \left\{0\right\}$$
$$=\frac{0}{Pr(\left\{X \geq0.5\right\})}$$
$$=0$$
Attempt on #2
$$E[X| |X|\geq0.5] = $$
$$ = 0,\;because\;E[X] = \mu\;and\;\mu=0$$

Comment: In general if $\alpha \geq 0$ then $\{ X \geq 0.75 \alpha \} \cap \{ |X| \geq 0.5 \}=\{ X \geq \max \{ 0.5,0.75\alpha \} \}$ which is not empty. The second one is correct but you need a little bit more justification (there is some symmetry to the region $|X| \geq 0.5$).

Comment: Also, there is a possibility that $X \le -0.5$ so you can't delete that

Comment: @Ian
How would I go about finding the probability for $\left\{X\leq max\left\{0.5,0.75\alpha\right\}\right\}$?
Why is $|X|\leq0.5$ relevant if E[X] itself is 0? What would be the probability of $|X|\leq0.5$?

Comment: @spaceisdarkgreen In an example my professor did, he simply said probability does not exist for negative values of X, so it was OK to remove.

Comment: @Jon I think you probably misunderstood that example, a normal distribution with mean zero assigns lots of probability to negative values. A common situation is that you're using a normal distribution to model variation in a quantity that is actually positive by its nature. (For example, a normal approximation to a binomial.) In this case you would usually have a mean that is 3 times bigger than the standard deviation or more, in which case the probability of negative values is negligible, even though it is technically not zero. This is definitely not the case when the mean is zero, though.

Comment: That said, the probability that $X$ is larger than some fixed value is easy to calculate, just use the table or software and symmetry.

Comment: @Ian How would I calculate the probability if $\sigma$ is a variable ($\sigma^2$) and not a numerical value? In this specific example #2 is 0 right?

Comment: #2 is zero, yes. If $\sigma$ is a variable then you'll need to write it in terms of some function that you think of as "known"; usually this is the standard normal CDF, $\Phi(x)=P(Z \leq x)$.

Comment: @Ian Am I on the right track?$P\{ X \geq \max \{ 0.5,0.75\alpha \} \}=\Phi(\frac{max\{0.5,0.75\alpha\}-\mu}{\sigma^2})=\Phi(\frac{max\{0.5,0.75\alpha\}}{\sigma^2})$

Comment: You need to do something to go from $\geq$ to $\leq$ and your denominator is wrong.

Comment: @Ian
$\Phi(z) = \frac{x-\mu}{\sigma}. \mu=0,\sigma = \sigma^2$. What is wrong there?

Comment: $\sigma$ is just $\sigma$; they gave you the variance and not the standard deviation.

Comment: @Ian
My book states: $Gaussian(\mu, \sigma) -> z=\frac{x-\mu}{\sigma}$. In this problem, $\mu=0$ and $\sigma = \sigma^2$, so wouldn't $z=\frac{x}{\sigma^2}$?

Comment: Most likely they expect you to interpret $\sigma^2$ as the variance otherwise there is no point in writing it that way.